# Help! Django media widget did not appear

Tags: python, django, django-forms

been scratching my head. I've followed the examples to use a jquery datepicker for my datefield in my form. Here are my code (note:indentation are correct in my code):

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
from myproject.customUsers.models import SchoolClass#,Student
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myproject.widgets import CalendarWidget

    class ConsentFormTpl(forms.Form):
        title =  forms.CharField()
        message = forms.CharField()
        deadline = forms.DateField(widget=CalendarWidget)
        availClass  = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SchoolClass.objects.all(),empty_label="None")
        students = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(groups__name='Students'),widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Students",is_stacked=False))
```

In my widgets file, I have:

```
class CalendarWidget(forms.DateInput):
    class Media:
        css = {
               'all':('css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css',),
        }
        js = ('js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js',)
```

Finally in my template I use `{{form.media}}`. Strangely, the css and js files for CalendarWidget did not appear in my html. (the files for FilteredSelectMultiple are there). I checked through the shell it seems already:

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> from myproject.widgets import CalendarWidget
>>> class C(forms.Form):
...    title = forms.DateField(widget=CalendarWidget)
... 
>>> c=C()
>>> print c.media
<link href="http://xyz.com/media/css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xyz.com/media/js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>
```

template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
                //some stuff here
                        })

            }

            //When user change classes, load new set of students
            $("select#id_availClass").change(function(){
                getStud( $(this).val() );
            })

            $("#id_deadline").datepicker();

            // Loads initial set of students when form loads
            getStud(-1);

        })
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xyz.com/media/admin/css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xyz.com/media/admin/css/forms.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/admin/js/core.js" />
{{ form.media }}
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="yes" value="Submit" />
</form> {% endblock %}
```

Update:I managed to print the form media out before pushing it into render_to_response. The files are there!

```
form = ConsentFormTpl()
        print form.media

    return render_to_response('consent_form/consent_form2.html',{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Any pointers people?

Comment: Can you post the base.html file and the the template html page(view > page source)?

Comment: I'm guessing you've already verified that you don't have some caching issue that you're still getting a previous version of your page?  As far as I can tell your code looks spot on...but I could be missing something as well.

Comment: How about django version?  Are you using something fairly recent?  Long shot....but again, your code sure seems right...and the fact you can print the media out at the shell and before render_to_response sure seems like something weird is happening.

Comment: Please post what I have asked you if you want to help you. Maybe our eyes will see more.

Comment: @Seitaridis, thanks for requesting me to post base.html. Ashamed to make such a simple mistake as not specifying the doctype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, thanks to @seitaridis, I managed to find out where my error was. I did not specify the doctype, and ` wasn't allowed. Gosh, I am embarrassed by such a simple mistake.

Comment: Could you elaborate on where and what added as doctype?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the top of your custom widgets file.

```
from django import forms
```

Comment: Although I guess this is dumb of me, as your myproject.widgets.py would not work if you didn't already have this would it.

Answer (score -1):

Could the problem be because you've given the `CalendarWidget` *class* instead of an *instance* in the `widget` keyword argument?

Try changing:

```
deadline = forms.DateField(widget=CalendarWidget)
```

to

```
deadline = forms.DateField(widget=CalendarWidget())
```

Comment: I think op is right in using widget=CalendarWidget...I'm doing the same thing and it is working for me.

Comment: To elaborate on my previous comment please see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/media/#media-on-forms.